# Laravel Class 'MongoDB\Driver\Manager' not found in centos

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel, centos

I got this error in Centos - VPS server, PHP MongoDB driver installed properly, and then extension also added.

Comment: You might want to add some more information to this question, Is the title the EXACT error that has happened?

Comment: you have to add extension in both `cli` and `apache` ini